# How to use an old docker image?

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose

I have one application based on java 7. Unfortunately, days ago, the java 7 docker image was updated to new version (u111) and when I rebuild my app image,  it is broken suddenly and failed to start again.

Now I am thinking to reuse my old java:7 image in the host machine.

BTW: I am using docker-compose.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I guess: you debug the problem to understand what changes. Then you figure what that means - if you better change your application; or if you have put constraints on the versions of docker images you are using. Beyond that, your question is way too broad. How are we supposed to understand how your app is using that docker image; and what changed inside it? You know, we can't help with such questions - as all the knowledge required to fix the problem only exists on **your** side.

Comment: @GhostCat . The application is  openDJ 2.5, a java based LDAP server  implementation. It failed to start when I rebuild the  java image from remote repository. I check the log and found a class path the openDJ relies on seems changed somehow.  I guess this is due to java:7 's updating. So I think maybe it is the quickest  way to make openDJ work by rollback to previous java:7 image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your tag to `java:7u101` to use the previous version of the image. `java:7` will always be the latest Java 7 update so need to be be more explicit if your app requires a specific older version.

All of the available tags are listed [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/library/java/tags/).